# how to .call a lamda in OpsCode Chef to be able to do a run time evaluation only?

Tags: ruby, variables, lambda, chef-infra

I have a question regarding Chef and the Lambda method to evaluate variables rather at run time than compile time. Check the snip below:

```
md5 = lambda { Digest::MD5.file("#{some_file}").hexdigest }
pp "md5: #{md5}"
```

This results in:

```
md5: #<Proc:0x000000000c153b08
```

But I do want to have the variable itself. What is the exact syntax to .call the lambda and get the actual variable? I am pulling my hair out for days.

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: Note that `"#{some_file}"` is likely redundant. If `some_file` is already a string, you can just use it as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several options to [`call`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Proc.html#method-i-call) a proc or lambda:

```
md5 = lambda { "foo" }

"md5: #{md5.call}"  #=> "md5: foo"
"md5: #{md5.()}"    #=> "md5: foo"
"md5: #{md5[]}"     #=> "md5: foo"
"md5: #{md5.yield}" #=> "md5: foo"
```

Each of the above can also accept arguments. This could be used for example to *pass* the filename: (`->` is a [lambda proc literal](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Lambda+Proc+Literals))

```
md5 = ->(filename) { Digest::MD5.file(filename).hexdigest }

"md5: #{md5.call(somefile)}"
"md5: #{md5.(somefile)}"
"md5: #{md5[somefile]}"
"md5: #{md5.yield(somefile)}"
```

Comment: also like that `md5 === somefile`

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate the lambda code, you can `call` it:

```
md5 = lambda { Digest::MD5.file("#{some_file}").hexdigest }
pp "md5: #{md5.call}"
```

The  `call` method  of  a lambda or generally, a Proc object in Ruby will evaluate the block given when creating the Proc and return the block's return value. Note that the result is not cached and each  `call` invocation will evaluate the block again.

Comment: Thanks! However, the other answer is more complete so there goes the kudos, but both are really helpful, thanks!